# How to convert values of a case class into Seq?

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and I am having to provide values extracted from an object/case class into a Seq. I was wondering whether there would be any generic way of extracting values of an object into Seq of those values in order?

Convert the following:

```
case class Customer(name: Option[String], age: Int)
val customer = Customer(Some("John"), 24)
```

into:

```
val values = Seq("John", 24)
```

Comment: Mixing a `String` and an `Int` in a `Seq` results in type `Seq[Any]`, an almost useless collection.

Comment: `case class` is like common `class` in scala, it has not method in std lib for getting field values as a sequence. Why you are need it? 
If you want store some information with field names and values maybe it would be good to use `Map[K, V]` instead of object of some class?

Comment: @lbrahim What if you have `Customer(None, 24)`? What `Seq` would you like to get?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

case class extends `Product` class and it provides such method:

```scala
case class Person(age:Int, name:String, lastName:Option[String])

def seq(p:Product) = p.productIterator.toList

val s:Seq[Any] = seq(Person(100, "Albert", Some("Einstain")))
println(s) //List(100, Albert, Some(Einstain))
```

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/oD7qk8u/0

Problem is that you will get untyped list/array from it. Most of the time it is not optimal way of doing things, and you should always prefer statically typed solutions.

Answer (score 5):

Scala 3 (Dotty) might give us [HList](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/4938) out-of-the-box which is a way of getting product's values without loosing type information. Given `val picard = Customer(Some("Picard"), 75)` consider the difference between

```
val l: List[Any] = picard.productIterator.toList
l(1)
// val res0: Any = 75
```

and

```
val hl: (Option[String], Int) = Tuple.fromProductTyped(picard)
hl(1)
// val res1: Int = 75
```

Note how `res1` did not loose type information.

Informally, it might help to think of an HList as making a case class more *generic* by dropping its name whilst retaining its fields, for example, whilst `Person` and `Robot` are two separate models

```
Robot(name: Option[String], age: Int)
Person(name: Option[String], age: Int)
```

they could both represented by a common "HList" that looks something like

```
(_: Option[String], _: Int) // I dropped the names
```

Answer (score 4):

If it's enough for you to have `Seq[Any]` you can use `productIterator` approach proposed by **@Scalway**. If I understood correctly you want also to unpack `Option` fields. But you haven't specified what to do with `None` case like `Customer(None, 24)`.

```
val values: Seq[Any] = customer.productIterator.map {
  case Some(x) => x
  case x => x
}.toSeq // List(John, 24)
```

Statically typed solution would be [to use](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) heterogeneous collection e.g. HList

```
class Default[A](val value: A)
object Default {
  implicit val int: Default[Int] = new Default(0)
  implicit val string: Default[String] = new Default("")
  //...
}

trait LowPriorityUnpackOption extends Poly1 {
  implicit def default[A]: Case.Aux[A, A] = at(identity)
}

object unpackOption extends LowPriorityUnpackOption {
  implicit def option[A](implicit default: Default[A]): Case.Aux[Option[A], A] = at {
    case Some(a) => a
    case None => default.value
  }
}

val values: String :: Int :: HNil =
  Generic[Customer].to(customer).map(unpackOption) // John :: 24 :: HNil
```

Generally it would be better to work with `Option` monadically rather than to unpack them.